# QSqlQuery GroupBy Slow

Tags: qt, sqlite, group-by, qsqlquery

i have a problem with QSqlQuery and GROUP BY.
My database is inMemory and is created like this:

```
query.exec("create table if not exists ProzSchnitte (id integer primary key autoincrement, Kanal uint, ProgNr uint, WkzNr uint, WkzBez blob, BearbNr uint, "
                                                     "Offset uint, Datum uint, Uhrzeit uint, count uint, SchnittHeader blob, xVals blob, yVals blob, Strom1 blob, Strom2 blob, Strom3 blob)");
```

I then writing my data into this table like this:

```
query.prepare(QString("INSERT INTO ProzSchnitte (Kanal, ProgNr, WkzNr, WkzBez, BearbNr, Offset, Datum, Uhrzeit, Count, SchnittHeader, xVals, yVals, Strom1, Strom2, Strom3) VALUES (%1, %2, %3, ?, %4, %5, %6,%7, %8, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ")
                          .arg(TempSchnitt.Header.Kanal).arg(TempSchnitt.Header.Programmnummer).arg(TempSchnitt.Header.Werkzeugnummer)
                          .arg(TempSchnitt.Header.Bearbeitungsnummer).arg(TempSchnitt.Header.Offset).arg(TempSchnitt.Header.Datum)
                          .arg(TempSchnitt.Header.Uhrzeit).arg(impCount));
query.bindValue(1,HeaderArray);
query.bindValue(2,x);
query.bindValue(3,y);
query.bindValue(4,Strom1);
query.bindValue(5,Strom2);
query.bindValue(6,Strom3);
query.exec();
query.finish();
```

After that i am reading the data like this:

```
QSqlQuery q(QSqlDatabase::database("ProzAnaDB"));
q.prepare("select * from ProzSchnitte GROUP BY Kanal, ProgNr, Offset, WkzNr, BearbNr, Count order by Count, Kanal, ProgNr, Offset, BearbNr");
q.exec();
```

The Execution of this is extremly slow and takes about 8 seconds but if i make a select without GROUP BY it is executed in under 10 milliseconds.

I have read that i may have to set so indexes in my table but i have no clue what that means or how i could do that.

I made an EXPLAIN of my query and this was the result.

```
QSqlRecord( 8 ) 
 " 0:" QSqlField("addr", int, generated: yes, typeID: 1) "0" 
 " 1:" QSqlField("opcode", QString, generated: yes, typeID: 3) "" 
 " 2:" QSqlField("p1", int, generated: yes, typeID: 1) "0" 
 " 3:" QSqlField("p2", int, generated: yes, typeID: 1) "0" 
 " 4:" QSqlField("p3", int, generated: yes, typeID: 1) "0" 
 " 5:" QSqlField("p4", QString, generated: yes, typeID: 3) "" 
 " 6:" QSqlField("p5", QString, generated: yes, typeID: 3) "" 
 " 7:" QSqlField("comment", , generated: yes, typeID: 5) ""
```

Can somebody explain me what i could do to boost the performance of this query?

Comment: Do you really need grouping by 10 columns?

Comment: yes i do need that but it doesnt matter by how much columns i group. With just 1 it is just as slow as with 10

Answer (score 1):

The correct command to analyze a query is not EXPLAIN but [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html), and you should do this in the command-line shell or another database tool so that you can view the result more easily.

Anyway, the most useful index for this query is one that matches both the ORDER BY and the GROUP BY (so reorder the GROUP BY columns):

```sql
CREATE INDEX whatever ON ProzSchnitte(Count, Kanal, ProgNr, Offset, BearbNr);
```

Comment: Thank you. Worked great. Went from 8 seconds per query to 10 milliseconds